# syntax error on INSERT INTO

Tags: excel, vb.net, ado.net, oledb

I had this error by clicking on the save button that saves the 3 textbox in an excel file. 
I managed to display the contents of excel file in a datagridview ... but I have not been able to save the data via OleDBCommanBuilder. 
it joined the code for any useful purpose:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; data source=D:\Users\mghazlan\Desktop\doss\DB.xls; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("", con)
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    cmd.CommandText = "select * from [Feuil$]"
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    builder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Fill(ds, "Feuil")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Feuil")


    ' MessageBox.Show(con.State)



End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ligne As DataRow = ds.Tables("Feuil").NewRow
    ligne("ID") = TextBox1.Text.ToString
    ligne("Nom") = TextBox2.Text.ToString
    ligne("Prenom") = TextBox3.Text.ToString

    ds.Tables("Feuil").Rows.Add(ligne)
    da.Update(ds, "Feuil")
    ds.AcceptChanges()
    MessageBox.Show("Ajouté avec Succès", "Succès", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What about calling `builder.GetInsertCommand()`. See what kind command it builds

Comment: I have already tried ... but no results :/

Comment: so, what your insert looks like? And also, try to insert using `ExecuteNonquery`and see if that works

Comment: Simple caracters ... like Column IDNumber contains Number 6 ... first name containe XXXXX and Last Name ...

Comment: I just tried ExecuteNonEquery ... everything goes well ... but nothing is recorded on the Excel file ...

Comment: first of all, I just noticed that you are not using `microsoft.ACE.Oledb` for connection. Use that - proven to work well. Why don't you add everything you have to your question. Including the output of your `builder.GetInsertCommand().commandText`...

Comment: I tried ..'builder.getInsertCommande.commandText' but no results compared to provider .. I chose the 'JET' saw that it was proposed as sites of connectionsstrings

Comment: This is proper way to connect to Excel http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/